# VB.NET: Convert Hashtable to Dictionary with generic value type

Tags: vb.net, generics, dictionary, hashtable

How can one do a conversion from `Hashtable` to `Dictionary` keeping the value generic? My idea is to have a function like the following:

```
Public Function Hashtable2Dictionary(Of T)(ht As Hashtable) As Dictionary(Of String, T)
    ' do conversion here
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Public Function Hashtable2Dictionary(Of T)(ht As Hashtable) As Dictionary(Of String, T)
    If ht Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, T)(ht.Count)
    For Each kv As DictionaryEntry In ht
        dict.Add(kv.Key.ToString(), CType(ht(kv.Value), T))
    Next
    Return dict
End Function
```

You cannot cast a `Hashtable` to a `Dictionary` directly. You can try to cast every object in the `HashTable` to `T`(`CType` uses some tricks to get the desired type, e.g. `String` to `Int32`). If it cannot be casted to the target type an `InvalidCastException` is raised.

Why do you need it? Maybe there's a better way to achieve what you want. In general you should avoid the non generic collections like `ArrayList` or `HashTable` nowadays.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I need this in order to work with legacy code :-)